# Vue.js - How to render data changes in child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have a parent component `Store` that has a child component called `Order`. The data from the parent is passed via `props` to its child, like so:

**parent**

```
<Order :order="order" />
```

**child**

```
props: ['order']
```

I need to use a new data variable in the child component called `orderIds`, so I declare that:

**child**

```
props: ['order'],
data: () {
  return {
    orderIds: Object.keys(this.order)
  }
}
```

Then, I render the `orderIds` in the view:

```
{{orderIds}}
```

Now, whenever the `order` data changes in the **parent**, it updates the prop `order` in the child, but it is not propagated through to `orderIds`.

How would I update `orderIds` when something changes in `order`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of data use a computed property.

```
computed: {
    orderIds: function () {
      return Object.keys(this.order);
    }
  }
```

Comment: But this way, we can't update orderIds in child component. It is common that we use props to initialize data and change data afterwards.

Comment: You can emit an event to update the order on the parent component and hence updating the `orderId` on child component, or you could use a computed setter, or you could initialize data with `order` and use computed property based on that. The answer I added was appropriate for the asked question.